# What normal form are the this relation in? Am I right?

Tags: database, database-design, dependencies

-

> R(a, b, c, d)

`Functional dependencies: None`

I think it is 0NF, because there are no functional dependencies.

> R(a, b, c, d)

`Functional dependencies: b->d AND a,b->c`

This should be 3NF, i think.

I am stuck at this one

> R(a, b, c, d, e)

`Functional dependencies: a->d,e AND a,d->b,c,e`

Answer (score 1):

There is always the trivial dependency,

```
a,b,c,d -> a,b,c,d
```

The key is the entire relation.  Not often useful, but not 0NF.

Answer (score 0):

> R(a, b, c, d)
>
> Functional dependencies: b->d AND a,b->c
>
> This should be 3NF, i think.

No, it's 1NF.  The only candidate key is `ab`. That means `b->d` represents a partial key dependency, so R's normal form must be lower than 2NF.